# Refresh List in Session after Button Click event is triggerd

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a `datatable` which i am passing to another page using `session`. On other page, i shifted session to datatable again and assign it to a datalist.

I want to remove a specific value from the `datalist` when `button click` event is triggered.

Can anyone advise how to achieve this. 
If this is not a good approach, can you please suggest a better solution.

```
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        If (Not Session("Operations") Is Nothing)) Then
            dt = CType(Session("Operations"), DataTable)
        Else
            If Not Session("dt") Is Nothing Then
                dt = CType(Session("dt"), DataTable)
            End If
        End If


        DataList1.DataSource = dt
        DataList1.DataBind()
```

**Updated:**

```
 For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

            Dim dr As DataRow = dt.Rows(i)

            If dr("AppID") = appId Then

                dr.Delete()
            End If

        Next
        dt.AcceptChanges()


        Session("Operations") = dt




        DataList1.DataSource = dt
        DataList1.DataBind()
```

Comment: so where you stucked, you can remove values from datatable

Comment: Yes. but how to remove it permanently. because the session still contains the values.

Comment: The list will display only those values for which operation is not performed yet.

Comment: if you want to remove from session too you can update it like this `Session("dt") = dt` after removing data from `DataTable`

Comment: I updated the datatable and assign it to datalist again. but still shows the old values. I have updated my question and insert the code.